# Look ahead search on document fields in azure DocumentDb

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

We are interested in using DocumentDb as a data store for a number of data sources and as such we are running a quick POC to establish whether it meets the criteria we are looking for.

One of the areas we are keen to provide is look ahead search capabilities for certain fields.  These are traditionally provided using the SQL LIKE syntax which does not appear to be supported at present.

Searching online I have seen people talking about integrating Azure search but this appears to be a very costly mechanism for such a simple use case.

I have also seen people mention the use of UDF's but this appears to require an entire collection scan which is not practical from a performance perspective.

Does anyone have any alternative suggestions?  One thing I considered was simply using a SQL table and initiating an update each time a document was inserted\updated\deleted?

Comment: This is really broad and opinion-soliciting. I don't think this really fits StackOverflow - you already mentioned full text search, of which there are plenty of options (including Azure Search as you mentioned).  This question seems more about pricing, as there's no programming issue here.

Comment: The question is programming based.  I am looking to see what solutions users have taken to solve the SQL like search capability that is currently missing in DocumentDb.  I want to use DocumentDb for the scalability and guaranteed performance at scale but can't see how to do it without this feature.  I note that I am not alone in this as there are several hundred votes for the feature at https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-documentdb/suggestions/6333414-implement-wildcards-when-searching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DocumentDB supports `STARTSWITH` and range indexes to support prefix/look ahead searching.

You can progressively make queries like the following based on what your user types in a text box:

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM hotel H WHERE STARTSWITH(H.name, "H")
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM hotel H WHERE STARTSWITH(H.name, "Hi") 
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM hotel H WHERE STARTSWITH(H.name, "Hil")
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM hotel H WHERE STARTSWITH(H.name, "Hilton")
```

Note that you must configure the collection, or the path/property you're using for these queries with a [range index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-indexing-policies#a-idcustomizingindexingpolicya-customizing-the-indexing-policy-of-a-collection). You can extend this approach to handle additional cases as well:

To query in a case-insensitive manner, you must store the lower case form of the search property, and use that for querying.

Comment: Many thanks Aravind.  This works great for simple lookups but not where complex part matching is required.

Comment: Iain, can you please provide a few different cases of complex part matching? I'd be happy to expand my answer if possible to cover those as well.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar situation, where a fast lookup was required, as a user typed search terms.

My scenario was that potentially thousands of simultaneous users would be performing such lookups; when testing this under load, to avoid saturation and throttling, we found we would have to increase the DocumentDB Request Unit (RU) throughput amount to a point that was not financially viable *for us, in our specific circumstances*.

We decided that DocumentDB was best used as the persistent store, and 'full' data retrieval - and this role it performs exceptionally well - while a small ElasticSearch cluster performed the role *it* was designed for - `text search`, `faceted search`, `weighted search`, `stemming`, and most relevant to your question, `autocomplete analyzers`and `completion suggesters`.

The subject of type ahead queries, creation of indexes, autocomplete analyzer and query time 'search as you type' in ElasticSearch can be found [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_query_time_search_as_you_type.html), [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_index_time_search_as_you_type.html) and [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html)

The fact that you plan to have several data sources would also potentially make the ElasticSearch cluster approach more attractive, to aggregate search data.

I used the Bitnami template available in the Azure market place to create relatively small instances, and most importantly, this allowed me to place the cluster on the same Virtual Network as my other components, which greatly increased performance.

Cost was lower than Azure Search (which uses ElasticSearch under the hood).